# Ordenamiento de burbuja y DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

tengo un problema que no he podido resolver, tengo que obtener un arreglo de un input de HTML con números separados con comas y regresarlo ordenado mediante un algoritmo de ordenamiento de burbuja, imprimiéndolo en el HTML.
Agradeceré toda la ayuda posible :D

```js
function sort() {
  var value = document.getElementById("arr").value;
  var split = value.split(",");
  bubbleSort(split);
  document.getElementById("valueInput").innerHTML = split;
}

function bubbleSort(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        let aux = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

```html
    <main>
        <h3>Sorting an array: </h3>
        <p>Introduce numbers separated with commas.</p>
        <form>
            <input id="arr" type="text" name="num" placeholder="1, 2, 3," pattern="[0-9,]" title="Just add numbers separated with commas." required="true">
            <button type="button" onclick="sort()">Sort</button>
        </form>

        <div class="resultado">
            <p id="valueInput"></p>
        </div>

    </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos errores:

1. El argumento de tu función le llamas `array` pero internamente lo manejas como `arr`, lo cual no tiene sentido.
2. Tienes que convertir los strings a números, de lo contrario, las comparaciones se efectuarán de manera incorrecta. Para ello basta un simple `map`.

Te adjunto tu código arreglado:

```js
function sort() {
  var value = document.getElementById("arr").value;
  var split = value.split(",").map(n => Number.parseInt(n));
  bubbleSort(split);
  document.getElementById("valueInput").innerHTML = split;
}

function bubbleSort(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        let aux = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = aux;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <h3>Sorting an array: </h3>
        <p>Introduce numbers separated with commas.</p>
        <form>
            <input id="arr" type="text" name="num" placeholder="1, 2, 3," pattern="[0-9,]" title="Just add numbers separated with commas." required="true">
            <button type="button" onclick="sort()">Sort</button>
        </form>

        <div class="resultado">
            <p id="valueInput"></p>
        </div>

    </main>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :D